# How do I make it so that the print statement stays on the same line while having my input to next one down

Tags: python

So I want to make it so the print output is in one line, and I did that using end, but my input happens on the same line [Shown here](https://gyazo.com/002b42ddf3f67b062d1016d0d7abcd63). I used the \n on the int, but that indents the program one line when I run it.

```
while True:

    guess = int(input("Number of characters: "))

    for i in range(int(guess)):
        print(random.choice(letters), end='',)
```

Comment: So, to be clear, the problem isn't anything to do with making text appear on the same line; it's about making a particular bit of text *not* appear on the same line. Yeah? Well, can you think of something you could output, that make it go to the next line? I don't understand how there's a real question here; just think about the tools you have and what you have seen them do. Think logically about the steps in your process, and when exactly a new line should happen.

Answer (score 2):

You do want to use `end=''` so that all of the print statements in your loop print to the same line.  But then, after your loop, you want to output a newline before you accept more input.  So you want this:

```
while True:
    guess = int(input("Number of characters: "))

    for i in range(int(guess)):
        print(random.choice(letters), end='',)
    print()
```

Sample run:

```
Number of characters: 7
acdeeda
Number of characters: 24
dbffdeebgccdfbfcfdgdbbcf
Number of characters:
```

Comment: The input is fine. It's just that (print(random.choice(letters)) is output is on the same line as the guess variable as shown in the picture. I want to have it like each input and output is on it's own line.

Comment: If you remove the `end=""` parameter from your `print` statement that might solve the problem you are describing.